# Setting phpdotenv values

Tags: php, laravel-5, environment-variables

I am using Laravel 5.2 and wonder, if there is a way to set values in the .env through a script?

Let's say I have an entry "setup". By default it is set to 0. But after finishing the setup, this entry should be set to 1.

Is there a possibilty to achive this? The readme of this library on github says nothing about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I found no solution, I wrote a package for Laravel 5.x. With this package you can manage your .env file without opening it and add/delete/change values manually:

[Brotzka/laravel-dotenv-editor](https://github.com/Brotzka/laravel-dotenv-editor)